# Scala map method not behaving as expected

Tags: scala

I'm new to Scala, so its probable that this is an incredibly obvious mistake.  However, I'm trying to cast a List[Object] into List[A], where A is a parameter in the class.

```
class AbstractHibernateDAO[A<:Serializable]{
  def findAll: List[A] = {
    val objList = currentSession.createQuery("from " + clazz.getName()).list()
    objList.map{_.asInstanceOf[A]}
  }
}
```

Eclipse is puking up:

```
type mismatch;  found   : ?0(in method findAll) => A where type ?0(in method findAll)  required: (some other)?0(in method findAll) => ? where type (some other)?0(in method findAll)    AbstractHibernateDAO.scala  /springHibernateNoXML/src/main/scala/my/package
```

I've also tried the long form

```
objList.map{obj => obj.asInstanceOf[A]}
```

and get the same result.

Can anyone give me a hand?

[EDIT - Additional information]

For those that requested, here's the full listing:

```
package name.me


import java.io.Serializable
import java.util.List
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinition
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository
import com.google.common.base.Preconditions
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory
import org.hibernate.Session
import collection.JavaConversions._

@Repository
@Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
class AbstractHibernateDAO[A<:Serializable]{

  val clazz: Class[A] = null
  @Autowired val sessionFactory: SessionFactory = null

  def currentSession: Session = {
    sessionFactory getCurrentSession
  }

  def findOne(id: Long): A = {
    Preconditions checkArgument(id != null)
    currentSession.get(clazz, id).asInstanceOf[A]
  }

  def findAll: List[A] = {
    val objList = currentSession.createQuery("from " + clazz.getName()).list()
    objList.map(_.asInstanceOf[A])
    //This works
    //objList.asInstanceOf[List[A]]
  }

  def save(entity:A){
    Preconditions checkNotNull entity
    currentSession persist entity
  }

  def update(entity: A){
    Preconditions checkNotNull entity
    currentSession merge entity
  }

  def delete(entity: A){
    Preconditions checkNotNull entity
    currentSession delete entity
  }

  def deleteById(entityId: Long){
    Preconditions checkNotNull entityId
    val entity = findOne(entityId) 
    Preconditions checkNotNull entity
    delete(entity)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick look at the [Hibernate API docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Query.html) shows that `Query.list()` returns a `java.util.List`, but you have a type annotation of `List[A]`, which is by default (from the [scala package object](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#package)) a `scala.collection.immutable.List`.

Which do you want to return?

for Java List, change your type annotation and cast the whole list:

```
class AbstractHibernateDAO[A<:Serializable]{
  def findAll: java.util.List[A] = {
    val objList = currentSession.createQuery("from " + clazz.getName()).list()
    objList.asInstanceOf[java.util.List[A]]
  }
}
```

for Scala List, use JavaConversions:

```
class AbstractHibernateDAO[A<:Serializable]{
  def findAll: List[A] = {
    val objList = currentSession.createQuery("from " + clazz.getName()).list()
    import collection.JavaConversions._
    objList.toList.asInstanceOf[List[A]]
  }
}
```

Comment: I want to return a scala.collection.immutable.List.  I should be receiving a java.util.List<Object> from Hibernate (at least this is my understanding).  I want to dynamically upcast this to a scala.collection.immutable.List<A>.

Comment: @babbitt well, do as I suggest in this answer. The reason it won't work with just a map and a cast is because the implicit in JavaConversions coverts the java.util.List into a Buffer, rather than a Scala List, and since a List is not a subclass of Buffer, the cast will fail. So you need the `toList` in there.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll take a look at this this afternoon when I can get back to this project.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure of the type of `objList`?  Is it really a `scala.collection.immutable.List` of `java.util.Object`?  You can check this easily by adding a type to your variable declaration:

```
val objList: List[java.util.Object] = ...
```

Assuming that's correct, your code seems fine.  But I can't run it without having all the other code.  I can do what you are trying with a simplified example:

```
def convertAll[A](data: List[java.lang.Object]): List[A] =
  data.map(_.asInstanceOf[A])

convertAll[java.lang.Integer](List(1,2).map(new java.lang.Integer(_)))
// List[java.lang.Integer] = List(1, 2)
```

However, you shouldn't need to cast each item in the `List`.  Try just casting the list to its new type:

```
objList.asInstanceOf[List[A]]
```

For example:

```
val x: List[java.lang.Object] = List(1,2).map(new java.lang.Integer(_))
x.asInstanceOf[List[java.lang.Integer]]
// List[java.lang.Integer] = List(1, 2)
```

Comment: I tried validating that the list was List[java.lang.Object], and found that it was of type Java.util.List[?0].  I do have collection.JavaConversions._ imported, which I presume was providing a dynamic upcast to scala.collection.immutable.List.  Casting the entire list worked.

Comment: @babbit are you sure this doesn't give a ClassCastException at runtime? (because it does when I try it in the REPL)

Comment: @Luigi no, I'm not sure.  I only had a few minutes to make the suggested code change and saw that it resolved the error eclipse was complaining about.  I have not yet run my tests against it (still need to convert my test suite from java).